# How to write case in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In sqlserver, I write a query in that i use "case" but it is giving error, this is my case.

```
(case when sm.SegCode =0 then '' else sm.SegCode = 7 end)
```

please help me.

Thanks for all for giving response, actually I have a parameter `@id`. Now I want to check when it is not zero I check that condition  `sm.segcode` else if `@id` is zero then I don't want to check the condition that is `sm.segcode = @id`.

Comment: post your full sql statement, please.

Comment: In SSMS set cursor on CASE, press F1 and you will see this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx.

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is just a way to return different values - it's **not** a flow control statement, e.g. you cannot use CASE to either execute this code or that code. Just return values...

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with the statement you showed:

- the syntactic error of `else sm.SegCode = 7`
- the attempted mixing of types with the empty string and the int

Try this instead:

```
case when sm.SegCode = 0 then '' else '7' end
```

Of course that is partially a guess, because I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve by setting the result to either an empty string or the integer 7.

Answer (score 1):

this would be syntactically correct:

```
case sm.SegCode when '0' then '' else '7' end
```

or

```
case sm.SegCode when 0 then NULL else 7 end
```

if that columns allows NULL's that is

you can see more about case when in the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Always try to return `Same DATA TYPE` value from `Case` statement, seems your first condistion returns `VARCHAR` whereas the `else` section returns `INT`, it's not possible, so best to convert each value to `VARCHAR`, so 7 will be `'7'` in `else` statement, thanks

```
(CASE
    WHEN sm.SegCode = 0 THEN '' 
ELSE '7' END)
```